# Is it possible to add an OnClick event in another component?

Tags: reactjs, onclick

I added an OnClick event in a custom component created by me, but it didn't work. I want to add an OnClick event to this component. When i click it, it will play a youtube video below. Is it not possible to do this?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import classes from "./Feature.module.css";
import { ButtonHorizontal, ButtonCircular } from "./Buttons";

function Feature() {

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const openVideo = () => {
    setOpen((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <div> 
     <ButtonHorizontal icon={faPlay} text="Watch Video" onClick={openVideo}/>
         {open ? (
          <iframe
          src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k2qgadSvNyU"
          frameborder="0"
          allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"
          allowfullscreen
          title="video"
        />
        ) : null}
   </div>
  );
}

export default Feature;
```

And buttons.js:

```
import React from "react";
import classes from "./Buttons.module.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faPlay} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

export function ButtonHorizontal(props) {
  return (
    <div className={classes.buttonHorizontal}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={props.icon} className={classes.icon}/>
      <div className={classes.text}>{props.text}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What's the code of `ButtonHorizontal`?

Comment: I added  it to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the `onClick` property to an actual HTML element. Something like `<div className={classes.buttonHorizontal} onclick={props.onClick}>` should work.

```
import React from "react";
import classes from "./Buttons.module.css";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faPlay} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

export function ButtonHorizontal(props) {
  return (
    <div className={classes.buttonHorizontal} onclick={props.onClick}>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={props.icon} className={classes.icon}/>
      <div className={classes.text}>{props.text}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: But i want to use ButtonHorizontal component for many purposes in different pages instead of default <Button>. How can i run different tasks in different pages when buttonhorizontal is clicked?

Comment: Adding onclick={props.onClick} to ButtonHorizontal component in Button.js solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps someone:
If you use typescript you should extends all properties from right Dom element to interface of your component. For example i'll take a Button component with button as container:

```
export interface ButtonProps
  extends DetailedHTMLProps<
    ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,
    HTMLButtonElement
  >{}
```

And than in component it will looks like:

```
export const Button = ({
   className,
   ...props
}: ButtonProps): JSX.Element => { return (
   <button
      className={cn(s.btn, className})} {...props} ></button)}
```

I use 'classname' plugin for setting a classnames from parents and do not override it by component's classnames.

In case, if you do not use typescript:

```
const Button = ({ className, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <button
      className={cn("btn", className)}
      {...props}
    ></button>
  );
};
```